# Read build-in colors value of Excel

Tags: c#, excel

How can I read hexadecimal color values in Excel using C#?

[image]

Comment: Please provide what you've done so far.

Comment: I have doing google to access this 'excel color theme' object in C# or in VBA. nothing found till now.

Comment: Like this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.tab.themecolor(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Your mentioned msdn link is about choosing colors for creating new themes. I want to read colors of built-in theme. For example In 2nd row(of attached screenshot) there is theme "Grayscale". so I want to get hex values of these 8 colors of "Grayscale". Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: Or is there any other way to get these color values, means using vba or macro ?

Comment: In my experience it is easier to discover how to perform such tasks in VBA and then convert the syntax to C#. Top of the list when I searched for "Excel VBA Color Themes" was [Exploring Theme Colors](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/blog/exploring_theme_colors/)

Comment: if it's a kind of one-off exercise (you just need to make a list of the colors so you can theme your application), you can use something like ColorPix (https://www.colorschemer.com/colorpix_info.php) which is a free utility that will give you the color values for whatever is under the cursor.  I've used it before when I've need to see the values for a specific color on a website.  Just load the program, mouse over those little boxes, and write down each value.